# Azure Container Instances Islolate containers in side group

Tags: azure-container-instances

I want to be able to deploy an ACI container group but I want none of the containers in the group to be able to communicate with one another. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups), containers can communicate on any port even if it's not exposed. Is there a way to lock down all containers within a group?

Comment: Why do you want to do this through ACI? Do you mind prefer other services?

Comment: For security purposes. Untrusted execution and cost savings

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, I don't think there is an appropriate way to achieve it through the ACI. Maybe you can install the firewall in the image and use it. But it's not good and it will make the image bigger.

I recommend you take a try to the AKS, it has the network policy between the pods. And you can deploy the images with only one container for each of them. You can get more details from the [Network policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#network-policies) of the AKS.